# Does this picture look like a burnt out LED lighting or is something wrong with the fixture itself?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, led, recessed-lighting

Does this picture look like a burnt out LED lighting or is something wrong with the fixture itself? The apartment was built a year and a half ago with these types of fixtures put in.

Is this just the LED (consumable) or is something wrong with the fixture itself (warranty)?

In the picture, the light switch is on and looks like half the LEDs are off completely and the other half is dim.

[image: Dim LED Lighting Fixture... LEDs or Fixture Issue?]

**EDIT:**

I took the cover off and below is what I found. It looks like one single LED is burnt out.

The question now is:

**1) Does this look like a normal burnout, or is something wrong with the driver/capacitor that may have caused this?**

2) It also looks like I need to replace at least one of these panels. However, there is one driver/capacitor (out-of-view) that runs four of these separate panels. The panels are all connected in a single circuit all soldered together. **Is this a DIY replacement, or an electrician one?**

[image: Burnt out single LED in LED fixture]

Comment: The weak point in LED lighting is the electroinc driver which converts line voltage AC to the correct current for the LEDs.  Within that, the weak point is capacitors.  This looks like a driver problem.

Comment: Understand that LEDs vary wildly in quality. If they used cheap capacitors (what Harper called a driver) then it's certainly possible this is the fixture itself. My general rule of thumb is if the bulbs don't look replaceable, they probably aren't. Individual LEDs like this are seldom replaceable. This is why I tend to shy away from all-in-one LED fixtures like this. Give me a standard bulb socket and let me buy my own.

Comment: led fixtures use large numbers of small leds in series. Just like Christmas lights when one goes you loose the whole set. Good luck with your warranty claim.  Note of caution these thing run very high voltage, don't go poking around trying to diagnose it if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: the fixure is fine, if it's not a part of the thing the LEDs are attached to, which needs replaced ASAP

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I posted a new picture with the cover off and found a single burnt out LED. Can you guys answer the two questions I added. Thanks again!

Comment: it would be a diy job to replace the board. Your problem will be finding a matching replacement.

Comment: Thanks @agentp so do you think this is a normal burnout? I've never seen an LED burnout so not sure if the scorch marks are normal (as seen in the additional picture with the cover off).

Comment: yes.(why they go I have no idea)  See what i mean about the series connection, each board is 21 leds in series, then the two boards are in series, so that one device failure takes out the whole thing.  Theoretically you could replace the one led, but the way those boards are constructed makes that pretty difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the helpful comments.

According to the answers provided in the comments, the burnout looks normal (@agentp) and the damaged board of LEDs can simply be replaced. The one LED is probably causing the whole fixture to go out like Christmas lights.

According to other comments, LEDs vary by quality and the most crucial part is the driver/capacitor whose job is to convert the electricity correctly (@Harper and @Machavity). This burnout may be a result of that component.

I'll replace the board and see if it goes again.

*As a side note, we had a similar LED fixture in the other room that went dim like this a year ago. I didn't take care of that one because the house was new and the building owner had an electrician take care of it.*